# How do I get a file's parent directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a path to a file, `c:\xxx\abc\xyz\fileName.jpg`, how can I get the file's parent folder? In this example, I'm looking for `xyz`. The number of directories to get to the file may vary.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) to get the directory path. If you only want the name of the directory, you can use [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to extract the base name from it:

```
>>> path = r'c:\xxx\abc\xyz\fileName.jpg'
>>> import os
>>> os.path.dirname(path)
'c:\\xxx\\abc\\xyz'
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path))
'xyz'
```

Answer (score 8):

Using python >= 3.4  [pathlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/) is part of the standard library, you can get the parent name with `.parent.name`:

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path(path).parent.name)
```

To get all the names use .parents:

```
print([p.name for p in Path(path).parents])
```

It can be installed for `python2` with `pip install pathlib`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following apprach.

(a) Split the full path to the file by the os spearator.

(b) Take the resulting array and return the elments with indexes ranging from [0: lastIndex-1]
- In short, remove the last element from the array that results from the split

(c) SImply join together the array that is one elment short using the os separator once again.
Should work for windows and linux.

Here is a class function exemplifying.

```
# @param
#   absolutePathToFile an absolute path pointing to a file or directory
# @return
#       The path to the parent element of the path (e.g. if the absolutePathToFile represents a file, the result is its parent directory)
# if the path represent a directory, the result is its parent directory
def getParentDirectoryFromFile(self, absolutePathToFile):
    splitResutsFromZeroToNMinus1 = absolutePathToFile.split(os.sep)[:-1]
    return  os.sep.join(splitResutsFromZeroToNMinus1) 
pass
```

Answer (score -2):

If all your paths look the same like the one you provided:

```
print path.split('\\')[-2]
```

Comment: This won't work on other OS. It's base idea to hard code path separator in code.

Comment: @ShitalShah I agree that this nearly 4 year old answer was not perfect, but OP had specific paths (with given path separators!) so the answer was simple and would work for him. Your comment was unnecessary and the downvote too.