# Climbing the directory tree with Python

Tags: python, directory, python-2.x

Let's say I have this folder structure:

```
My Project
├── One
│   ├── Another Thing
│   └── Two
│       ├── Three
│       │   └── foo.py
│       └── Whatever
└── Something Else
```

From `foo.py`, using Python 2, how would I get a list of all its parent directories? It should look something like this:

```
['My Project', 'One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

Comment: So you want to find the full path of the *current Python module*?

Comment: @MikeScotty: at the very least, include *in your comment here* what that link is about. Just such a link is not constructive as it lacks any and all context. See [Is idownvotedbecau.se recommended?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356051) I've deleted your comment, if you want to re-post, please address those concerns.

Comment: Hi, try taking a look at this question, it might give you an idea of what to do [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525697/how-do-i-get-a-files-parent-directory)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, and ideally in a list (although a string could also work, since I can split it by `/`)

Comment: @jeffchef That seems to only be for going up by one directory -- I need the whole path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the path of the current Python module by using the [`__file__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) set on all Python modules when Python loads them from a file on disk. This is a string representing the absolute or relative path (the latter usually only when it's the `__main__` script) to the source file or `.pyc` byte-cache file of the module.

Use the [`os.path` module](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) to a) ensure that the path is absolute, and b), get all the directory names:

```
import os

HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def path_list(pathname):
    drive, directory = os.path.splitdrive(pathname)
    path = [] if not drive else [drive]
    # with no UNC prefix, normpath guarantees the path uses os.sep
    path += filter(None, os.path.normpath(directory).split(os.sep))
    return path
```

The [`os.path.splitdrive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive) call is needed to on Windows, where network (UNC) paths can start with `\\hostname\mount` or with `C:\\` (drive letters). The above includes such a prefix as the first element. Another happy side-effect of splitting of a UNC prefix is that this avoids one corner-case where `os.path.normpath()` would not replace `os.altsep` separators (`/` on Windows) with `\` (the Windows `os.sep` value) if the path starts with the special `\\?\` or `\\.\` prefixes.

Demo:

```
>>> __file__ = os.path.join(os.sep, 'My Project', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'foo.py')
>>> __file__
'/My Project/One/Two/Three/foo.py'
>>> HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
>>> HERE
'/My Project/One/Two/Three'
>>> path_list(HERE)
['My Project', 'One', 'Two', 'Three']
```

On Python 3.x, or if you are prepared to install a [backport](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/), you can also use the [`pathlib` library](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html); it provides `Path` instances that have a [`Path.parts` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) that gives you exactly the same info (with the root part represented by `os.sep` or the drive letter or UNC path on Windows):

```
try:
    from pathlib import Path
except ImportError:
    # pathlib2 backport
    from pathlib2 import Path

HERE = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
path_list = HERE.parts[1:] if HERE.root else HERE.parts
```

(Note: `Path.parts` produces a tuple, if you must have a list, pass the result to `list()` first).

You may also be interested in the [`Path.parents` sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents), which gives you all the parent directories as `Path` instances, in reverse order:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> HERE = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
>>> HERE
PosixPath('/My Project/One/Two/Three')
>>> HERE.parts[1:] if HERE.root else HERE.parts
('My Project', 'One', 'Two', 'Three')
>>> list(HERE.parents)
[PosixPath('/My Project/One/Two'), PosixPath('/My Project/One'), PosixPath('/My Project'), PosixPath('/')]
```